# Python Requests: Handling JSON response, storing to list or dict?

Tags: python, json, list, python-requests

I'm using the python requests library to GET data from an api.
The data is returned in a large json array called messages. There are many individual 'message' sub-level jsons' contained within (see a sample of the json response at the bottom).

In this json response, for each message, there are only a few (2 or 3) data points that I care about. I need to take these few data points, and store them to something (list of list, dictionary, etc.) so that I can reference it later, store to an object and use from another function.

The data points I need to store are `id`, `conversationId`, and `body. The` id`is unique, while the`conversationId` is shared among all messages in a conversation, so is not unique.

1. I would first like to ask what you think the best way to go about accomplishing this. I'm guessing a list of lists, or a dictionary of lists? I'm too new to know which would be a better solution.
2. Additionally, whatever method is chosen, I will need to know how to reference them and call them by id to store to an object from another function. I have yet to figure out how to do that successfully.

Here are a few things I have tried just to get a rough idea of how I can do this:

```
response=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p)
messages=json.loads(response.text)
for message in messages:
    print(message['body'])
```

^^ here I'm just trying to see if I can reference a specific message's body, did not work.

```
r=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p)
inbound_dict = {}
inbound=json.loads(r.text)
for item in inbound['messages']:
    inbound_dict[item['conversationId']] = item['body']
print(inbound_dict)
```

^^ This one actually does work somewhat, but doesn't allow me to organize the data effectively to be called later on. when I print the dictionary, it shows me the *newest* value, because the key is not unique... so it's overwriting instead of appending. This is what makes me thing a list of lists would be best.

In the end, I want a solution where the data is organized by `conversationId` in a dictionary or something similar with a structure like this, where I can reference messages by `conversationId`, or `msgId`, and a clean easy to read way to store it all... `:)`

```
Messages
     |___                  msgId:
         |_conversationId-[
         |                 body
         |                 msgId:
         |_conversationId-[
         |                 body
         |                 msgId:
         |_conversationId-[
                           body
```

Finally, here's a sample of the json. Please keep in mind that I'm still learning and getting up to speed with python. Thank you all for your time!

```
b'{"id":1005672,"messages":[{"id":4461048,"body":"Mnow test test","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"INCOMING","outgoing":false,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783232355,"attachments":[]},{"id":4461049,"body":"THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL (716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"AUTO_RESPONSE","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783233546,"attachments":[]},{"id":4620511,"body":"test sms,test sms","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":17297,"status":"DELIVERED","error":null,"kind":"API","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1577987093930,"attachments":[]},...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can have multiple items with the same conversation_id, then you can do something like this:

```
r=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p).json()
inbound_dict = {}
for item in r['messages']:
    conv_id = item['conversationId']
    if conv_id not in inbound_dict:
        inbound_dict[conv_id]=[{'msg_id' : item['id'], 'body' : item['body']}]
    else:
        inbound_dict[conv_id].append({'msg_id' : item['id'], 'body' : item['body']})

print(inbound_dict)
```

The resulting data structure is a dictionary with conversation_id as keys and each conversation_id maps to a `list` of `dict` items. each item stores the message_id and body of a particular message. You may then iterate over the messages for a particular conversation by retrieving the list of messages stored for conv_id key.

Alternatively, you may choose the following data structure to map:
`{conv_id -> { message_id : {message info ...}, ...}`.

This can be implemented like so:

```
r=requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p).json()
inbound_dict = {}
for item in r['messages']:
    conv_id = item['conversationId']
    if conv_id not in inbound_dict:
        inbound_dict[conv_id]={item['id'] : {'msg_id' : item['id'], 'body' : item['body']}}
    else:
        inbound_dict[conv_id][item['id']] = {'msg_id' : item['id'], 'body' : item['body']}

print(inbound_dict)
```

In this case you can access a message directly from a conversation if you know the con_id and the message_id.

so it really depends on the downstream utility for this data structure.

Note, the above can be accomplished with list comprehensions as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with a combination list- and dictionary-comprehension like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


response = b'{"id":1005672,"messages":[{"id":4461048,"body":"Mnow test test","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"INCOMING","outgoing":false,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783232355,"attachments":[]},{"id":4461049,"body":"THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL (716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"AUTO_RESPONSE","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783233546,"attachments":[]},{"id":4620511,"body":"test sms,test sms","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":17297,"status":"DELIVERED","error":null,"kind":"API","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1577987093930,"attachments":[]}]}'

data = json.loads(response)

messages = [
    {'id': message['id'],
     'conversationId': message['conversationId'],
     'body': message['body']} for message in data['messages']
]

pprint(messages, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 4461048, 'conversationId': 1005672, 'body': 'Mnow test test'},
 {'id': 4461049,
  'conversationId': 1005672,
  'body': 'THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL '
          '(716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS'},
 {'id': 4620511, 'conversationId': 1005672, 'body': 'test sms,test sms'}]
```

You could make the processing more data-driven and eliminate a lot of the repetitive coding in the comprehensions thus making it even more succinct by doing it like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data_points = 'id', 'conversationId', 'body'
response = b'{"id":1005672,"messages":[{"id":4461048,"body":"Mnow test test","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"INCOMING","outgoing":false,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783232355,"attachments":[]},{"id":4461049,"body":"THIS NUMBER DOES NOT CURRENTLY ACCEPT TEXT MESSAGES PLEASE CALL (716) 444-4444 TO WORK WITH ONE OF OUR INTAKE SPECIALISTS","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":0,"status":"RECEIVED","error":null,"kind":"AUTO_RESPONSE","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1576783233546,"attachments":[]},{"id":4620511,"body":"test sms,test sms","conversationId":1005672,"locationId":2045,"contactId":12792806,"assignedUserId":17297,"status":"DELIVERED","error":null,"kind":"API","outgoing":true,"reviewRequest":false,"type":"SMS","readDate":0,"respondedDate":0,"sentDate":1577987093930,"attachments":[]}]}'
data = json.loads(response)
messages = [{dp: message.get(dp) for dp in data_points}
                for message in data['messages']]

pprint(messages, sort_dicts=False)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your attention. Wonderful answer, however I'm getting a "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes, or bytearray, not response".. I believe this is because mine is a request/json response vs you explicitely declaring the 'response' object. Any tips on how to fix for my purposes? I think it's because i'm trying to pprint a dictionary using your example.

Comment: What line is causing the `TypeError`? Using `pprint()` isn't important, and is just being used to pretty-print the `messages` list that was created. Use plain `print()` if that's giving you a problem. Note I'm using Python 3.8.1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I'm using python 3.7.1. The line giving the type error is: data=json.loads(response). If I change the request line to include a .json() at the end, and change the problem line to: data=json.load(response), error changes to "'function' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: If your question had a [mre], I wouldn't have needed to simulate the source of the json data. Regardless, it seems like you ought to be able to apply the technique illustrated in my answer to do the processing you want.

Comment: Yea well, I'm working with a private platform's api so I wouldn't be able to provide you with an exact example without providing our api token/key.. Considering how the whole discrepency has to do with the fact that my data is coming as a returned response, and yours is not. thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: As I said, it ought to be very easy to apply my answer to what you're doing. Just make `data = requests.get(url + id, headers=h, params=p).json()` or something very similar.

Comment: As I did. You and your answer were very helpful. If I could give you, as well as the other gentleman both the answer, I would have. Thanks again.

Comment: You can't Accept more than one answer, but you can Vote-up more than one…

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want your messages in a data structure retrievable by conversation. Here's is what I would do:

```
from pprint import pprint

#with this data structure whenever we refer to a conversation, if it
#doesn't exist, it gets created
from collections import defaultdict
inbound_dict = defaultdict(dict) 

inbound=json.loads(data)
for item in inbound['messages']:
    print (item)

    current_conversation=inbound_dict[item['conversationId']]
    #inbound_dict retrives the apropriate conversation,
    #   or creates a new one for us to fill
    current_conversation[item["id"]] = item['body'] #add our item to it.

    #or if there's a chance we might want *everything* else about the
    #message later even if just the date in order to preserve
    #conversation ordering or whatever:

    #currentconversation[item["id"]] = item

pprint(inbound_dict)
```

But that might be overkill, depending on what processing you are going to do later, and what processing it is. If you're just going to let them choose a conversation, and display the last 20 messages, a list which is slice-able might be the best choice for the inner data structure, in which case, I'd to this:

```
from pprint import pprint

#with this data structure whenever we refer to a conversation, if it
#doesn't exist, it gets created
from collections import defaultdict
inbound_dict = defaultdict(list) 

inbound=json.loads(data)
for item in inbound['messages']:
    print (item)

    current_conversation=inbound_dict[item['conversationId']]
    #inbound_dict retrives the apropriate conversation,
    #   or creates a new one for us to fill

    current_conversation.append(
        (item["id"], item['body'])
        ) # here we add our item to it, in this case a tuple of id and body

    #or if there's a chance we might want *everything* else about the
    #message later even if just the date in order to preserve
    #conversation ordering or whatever:

    #currentconversation.append(item)

pprint(inbound_dict)
```

Basically the same operation, but with defaultdict providing us with a different type of inner collection to fill.

Comment: In your first example. I get a "KeyError: 1005672", which is I suppose an issue with using the conversationId as the key? Any idea how to resolve? Going to try your second solution now...

Comment: The second solution is actually pretty great, any direction on how I would be able to select single messages from the list that is printed at the end?

Comment: Which line is giving you the key error? I'm confused because the conversationID line should be the same in both.